# Assign points within 150 meter buffer of each other the same unique identifier?

Tags: qgis, buffer, analysis

I have a bunch of points on a QGIS map. Each point is a unique sampling event. However, some of these points have been sampled multiple times but there is no common identifier in the attribute data to determine this. The only way we can see this is by looking at the map and seeing points very close to each other.

I am wondering if anyone has a method to assign points within a 150 meters of each other a common identifier?

Comment: The "dbscan" clustering tool in 3.4 should do this

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Can you submit so I can upvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the "dbscan" spatial clustering algorithm from the Processing Toolbox - this is designed for this type of auto clustering.